# Plot RGB using rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, matplotlib, rgb

When plotting and RGB image using `rasterio`, I have seen that it is necessary to normalize the values first (0-1) and the use `show`. I am using the following code for that:

```
def norm(band):
    band_min, band_max = band.min(), band.max()
    return ((band - band_min)/(band_max - band_min))

b2 = norm(S_images[0].astype(numpy.float))
b3 = norm(S_images[1].astype(numpy.float))
b4 = norm(S_images[2].astype(numpy.float))

# Create RGB
rgb = numpy.dstack((b4,b3,b2))

# Visualize RGB
plt.imshow(rgb)
```

When reading the `rasterio.plot.show` documentation, there is a paramter called `adjust'

> adjust ('linear' | None) – If the plotted data is an RGB image, adjust
>   the values of each band so that they fall between 0 and 1 before
>   plotting. If ‘linear’, values will be adjusted by the min / max of
>   each band. If None, no adjustment will be applied.

Is this parameter doing the same as my `norm` function? Does it work only if I load a multi-chanel RGB image or can I use it when providing a `np.stack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can pass an array.  The documentation specifies:

> ```
> rasterio.plot.show(source, etc...)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> - source (***array*** or dataset object opened in 'r' mode or Band
>     or tuple(dataset, bidx))

Yes, it's the same. Demo using `rasterio.plot.adjust_band` that `show` uses to do the adjustment:

```
import rasterio.plot as rp
import numpy as np

def norm(band):
    band_min, band_max = band.min(), band.max()
    return ((band - band_min)/(band_max - band_min))

arr = np.arange(255, dtype=np.float32)
print(np.all(rp.adjust_band(arr) == norm(arr)))
```

```
True
```

Comment: Great, I can avoid then the my `norm` function. I was trying to use `adjust` has a parameter when calling `rasterio.plot.show` and that is why I was getting the error. Using first `rasterio.plot.adjust_band(arr)` to normalize the band and then using that output for the plot works fine. Thanks